# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, javapoet

I am getting below error when i build my application.Any help would be appreciated.

**Root:build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
```

**app:build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
    options.fork = true
    options.incremental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.10.0'
    implementation ("org.checkerframework:checker:2.1.10")
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.2.0'
}
```

> FAILURE:Build failed with an exception.
>   *Where:Settings file'/Users/Documents/android/MyApplication5/settings.gradle'
>   *What went wrong:Could not compile settings file'/Users/anand/Documents/android/MyApplication5/settings.gradle'.>startup failed:General error during semantic analysis:Unsupported major version 57
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Unsupported major version 57
>
> 1error

Comment: You're trying to load a class compiled for OpenJDK 13 with an older JVM. For example, your gradle may be picking a wrong JDK install for itself or for the compilation (those can be different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure both target and source version in your pom.xml file are the same.
Edit: There is no separate JREs for Java 9+ so make sure your JRE path leads to your JDK.

Comment: Any fisible solution for this as I am using jdk version 8 in my code